# How to find information between two words excluding white spaces using python re?

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to develop a script using python that detects if there is something between two words. I am using regular expression `r'Madrid:(.*?)Newyork'` for this:

```
import re

string_1 = "Madrid: good bars Newyork: good building Warranty: No"
pattern = r'Madrid:(.*?)Newyork'
searchObj = re.search(pattern, string_1, re.I)
if searchObj:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This is working fine the problem is that it also detects whitespaces, and when I have whitespaces it should not find anything. I would like to develop an expression that excludes a whitespace from the match. For example, for these two is match is true and should be false:

```
string_2 = "Madrid: Newyork: good building Warranty: No"
string_3 = "Madrid:      Newyork: good building Warranty: No"
```

I am trying with `[^\s]` but Is not working, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
reg = r'Madrid:(.*?\S.*?)Newyork'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d7NBQG/1)

`\S` in the middle ensures you are not matching all whitespaces between start and end strings.

Answer (score 1):

Without using another regex you can remove all whitespaces:

```
searchObj = re.search(pattern, string_1.replace(" ", ""), re.I)
```